# The StratifiedShuffleSplit (in sklearn) returns different proportion each time

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using the [`stratifiedShuffleSplit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html) in sklearn to split the training data into batches. So that every batch I feed into NN will have the same class proportion as the training set. Or in other words, I would like to preserve the same percentage of each class for each batch as the training set.

What I am confused is that for each iteration, each batch has little bit difference. It doesn't follow the exact percentage of training set, although it has similar trend. Why doesn't [`stratifiedShuffleSplit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html) give the exact percentage?

So now, I just write the code by myself to have the exact same percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have 11 points and want 70% traning set. How many points would you take?

7? Then it is 63.64%

8? The it is 72.73%

`StratifiedShuffleSplit` takes sometimes 7, sometimes 8. Therefore each batch has a small difference. Everything is fine.

Comment: Thank you lanenok. When the data is more or less balanced, it is ok. When the data is quite unbalanced, the small disturbance can be removed out the classes with small amount.